# What is the mechanism that redis expire works? Using callback or server keeps pinging

Tags: redis

I'm curious that how Redis implemented its expiration? 
Did redis use callback to expire keys or server need keep pinging redis to check expiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no callback and no need to check expiration. With every access to a key, Redis first checks whether it has expired.

In addition, an active expiry is performed with an internal cron (every 100ms). In it, Redis tries expiring the volatile keys that it tracks in an internal data structure.

From your question, it appears that you're interested in getting notified about expiration events. If that is the case, you should read the documentation page about [Redis Keyspace Notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) that explains how to do exactly that.

Comment: Read the documentation, do a search on Google - there are a few articles about the inner workings, ask the community and review the source code

Comment: @ItamarHaber Hey! BTW you know that keyspace notifications for key expiration isn't really useful if you want to receive a notification just when the key actually expires. I believe that the best approach is using an scheduler and schedule a notification